# 24 men and women, meet a new person each round

Tags: combinatorics

I have 24 men and 24 women. Divided them in groups of 8 (4 man, 4 woman). There are 3 rounds and 6 tables where they will be seated. Can every man meet a different man AND woman for these 3 rounds? If not, how would the arrangement be of they only met a different woman in the 3 rounds?

I tried something like this:

```
    R1  R2  R3
T1  1A  3B  5C
T2  2B      
T3  3C      
T4  4D      
T5  5E      
T6  6F
```

Comment: Do you mean 6 groups per round? So 18 groups across the 3 rounds?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the condition.  A given man $X$ will be in a group with $9$ other men in the $3$ rounds, and $12$ women  Is the requirement that these $9$ men and $12$ women are distinct, or only that there be at least one man and one woman in the group that $X$ has not met before?

Comment: One man will be seating at a table with 3 other men and 4 other women. This is round 1. Then they switch round 2 and he meets 3 other new men and 4 other women. Same again for the last round. It's possible that they meet a new woman every time for the total of 3 rounds, but is it also possible they meet new men or will they always meet someone else twice (or more).

Comment: In each "round" a man meets three men and four women (at the same table). Since this will (over the three rounds) his involving meeting men nine times and women twelve times, out of 23 men and 24 women, it seems likely that this would be feasible.  To simplify matters, I'd first focus on the scheduling of just the men.  Such a schedule will also then apply to the women by themselves.  Then I'd try to "marry" the two schedules together, hoping that a suitable matching occurs by chance.

Comment: @hardmath I've been thinking along much the same lines, but it seems to me that there's no trouble marrying the men and women.  If we call the men $A,B,\dots,X$ and the women  $a,b,\dots,x$ the after we get a suitable schedule for the men, can't we just seat the the lowercase letters at the same tables as the corresponding uppercase letters?  For example, if $A,B,C,D$ are the men at the table, seat $a,b,c,d$ with them.  I think this must work, mustn't it?

Comment: @saulspatz:  That is an excellent idea.  You are essentially scheduling the 24 pairs $(A,a),(B,b),\ldots,(X,x)$.

Comment: This should be doable. Represent the men as $A,B,\dots X$.  For the first round, seat $ABCD$, $EFGH$, ... $UVWX$.  For the second round, seat the men cyclically: $A$ at table $1$, $B$ at table $2$, .. $E$ at table $5$, $F$ at table $6$, $G$ at table $1$ and so on.  For the third round, we have to choose $6$ sets of $4$ men each so that no pair has occurred before, and each man occurs once.  This is a set exact cover problem which can be attacked by Knuth's dancing links algorithm.  Then seat the women as described in an earlier comment.

Comment: I'll write a program to implement the idea in my previous comment sometime today.

Comment: You are on to something!!! Of course it could be possible to change the rounds or tables in a certain way that it WOULD be possible, Maybe with such a program it's calculatable?

Comment: The only problem with what I've suggested is that each man is paired with a woman that he sits with in all $3$ rounds.  I'm not sure if that violates the condition or not.  I don't understand your last comment.  What would be possible?

Comment: In fact, I've got each man sitting with $9$ different men and $10$ different women, so it doesn't seem to work.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I mean that if it's not possible with 24 men and 24 women to never see somebody twice on a table, maybe it's possible with more/less rounds or more/less tables?

Comment: Don't you have a specific problem in mind?  I imagined you were trying to organize a real event.  What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Yes this is a specific problem but you say it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is a combinatorial problem in the topic of [resolvable block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design).  However the condition that each person meets *at least* one new man and one new woman in each round is *weaker* than what is often imposed, namely never meeting any one person more than once. The Question's present formulation makes it easy to provide a solution.

As @saulspatz points out, pairing off the men and women into $24$ pairs who will be seated together in each round makes a solution simpler to find and describe.  Let $P_i = (m_i,w_i)$ denote the pairing of the $i$-th man and the $i$-th woman; our numbering within the genders is fixed but arbitrary.

Then one easily finds three rounds in which each pair $P_i$ is seated with at least one different pair $P_j$, thus guaranteeing that each person meets at least one new man and one new woman in each round.  For simplicity we will just list the blocks as $4$-subsets of subscripts (from $1$ to $24$) to give the table seatings of each round.

Without loss of generality the first round can be these simple subsets, where subscripts are taken in order:

$$ \{1,2,3,4\};\{5,6,7,8\};\{9,10,11,12\};\{13,14,15,16\};\{17,18,19,20\};\{21,22,23,24\} $$

The second round can be constructed so that no two pairs that met in the first round would then meet again:

$$ \{1,8,15,22\};\{2,5,12,19\};\{3,10,13,20\};\{4,11,18,21\};\{6,9,16,23\};\{7,14,17,24\} $$

The third round can then be scheduled as follows:

$$ \{1,6,11,16\};\{2,7,12,21\};\{3,8,17,22\};\{4,13,18,23\};\{5,10,15,20\};\{9,14,19,24\} $$

Some of the pairings that meet in the third round *did* also meet earlier.  For example $P_2$ and $P_{12}$ meet in the third round, but also met in the second round. Similarly $P_{10}$ and $P_{20}$ meet in both the second and third rounds.  Nonetheless every pairing meets *some* new pairing in every round.

The result is that over the course of all three rounds, every person meets *at least* eight people of the same gender and nine people of the opposite gender.  Accordingly each person meets at least one new person of either gender in every round.

**How the rounds were constructed**

It is not obvious, but after the labeling for the first round, the second and third rounds were constructed by picking a "stride" greater than one and relatively prime to $24$, and then converting an arithmetic sequence with that common difference to a permutation of $(1,2,\ldots,24)$ by taking them modulo $24$.

For the second round this common difference ("stride") was $7$, while for the third round it was $5$.  One can view the first round as the result of taking a "stride" of $1$.  The construction forces the occurrence of each subscript exactly once in some block of each round, i.e. the "resolvable" property of the design.